# Jquery Mobile Multiple html app functioning improperly with cordova dialogs plugin

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I am just learning about Jquery Mobile's multiple html architecture for developing phonegap apps,currently I am facing a strange issue in it which I have never come across in Jquery Mobile Single Page Architecture.

App Logic I need to Implement:
  I am having two html files (index.html,second.html) I could navigate to second.html from index.html no problem in that and now from second.html I have to navigate back to index.html but before navigating to previous page the app must get the user confirmation based on that the navigation have to take place(I am using cordova dialogs plugin for this).

Here is my code

> index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />        
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/backcheck.js"></script>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section data-role="page" id="home">
            <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Sample</h1>
                <a href="second.html" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="forward" data-url="second.html">Forward</a>
            </header>
            <article data-role="content">
                <h6>This is Home Page</h6>
                <a href="#spasample" data-role="button">Single Page Architecture Page</a>
            </article>
        </section>
        <section data-role="page" id="spasample">
            <h1>Sample Page 2</h1>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="back" class="backer" >back</a>
            </header>
            <article data-role="content">
                <h6>This is Second Page</h6>
            </article>
        </section>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

> second.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />        
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />


    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section data-role="page" id="secondpage">
        <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Sample Page 2</h1>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="back" class="backer" >back</a>
        </header>
        <article data-role="content">
            <h6>This is Second Page</h6>
        </article>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/backcheck.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </section>      

</body>
```

Problem Faced:
   Whenever I click on back button in second.html page it is prompting a confirm box and if i click on any button its call back function is not called immediately instead it is being called only if i click the back button again.What is the reason behind this??

Kindly review my code and help me to fix it!

Comment: and the code where you use the dialogs plugin? you don't have to add the scripts and css on the second page, jquery mobile load just the content using AJAX

Comment: ok jcearmobile,I will use them only in index.html from now,even after changing that the results are the same :(

Comment: jcearmobile,thanks for pointing out my mistake I have fixed the problem by excluding backchecker.js in second.html now the app is functioning as it has to be